# Matching C++ code with C code

Tags: c++, c, printf

I'm trying to get a grasp on C code. Here I am trying to replicate this code in C with code in C++. Or more particularly, I am trying to convert this code from printf to cout using iostream and iomanip instead of printf and and cstdio.

```
//C CODE 
#include <cstdio> 
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std; 

int main() { 
 string header_text = "Basic IO"; 

 srand(0); 
 printf("%-10s::\n", header_text.c_str()); 
 for (int i=0; i<4; i++) { 
 int number1 = rand()%1000; 
 float number2 = (float)number1/91.0; 
 printf("<%3d, %7.4f>\n", number1, number2); 
 } 
 printf("\n");
}
```

And now I want to convert this to C++.

Here is my attempt:

```
//C++ code
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string header_text = "Basic IO";

    srand(0);
    cout << setw(10) << left << header_text << "::\n";

    for (int i=0; i <4; i++) {
        int number1 = rand()%1000;
        float number2 = (float)number1/91.0;
        cout << "<" <<number1 <<setw(3) << ","   <<setw(7) << setprecision(5)  << number2  << ">\n";
    }


}
```

It looks like it is mostly correct except the 10.0549 becomes 10.055 in the C++ code.
Any idea what is wrong with my C++ code? Although, there could be a couple more errors with it as I'm still very new to understanding  C.

Comment: The original code already mixes typical [tag:c] code with [tag:c++]??

Comment: The original code is C++, not C.

Comment: There might be slight differences in implementation of output precision, or you're not using exact equivalents.

Comment: The original has a precision of 4 (%7.4f) you use a precision of 5.

Comment: For the example given, the C++ aspects of the original "C" code is IMO rather irrelevant, as it doesn't have an impact on the output, which the poster is focussing on. Technically it's correct though, that this is not C.

Comment: When I tried using precision of 4 it didn't give the right output. It still doesn't. I'm just not really sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: problem with C like casting in C++?

Comment: Just a hint: in C++, instead of using rand(), consider using the new PRNG APIs. They're awesome. rand() % max is a poor way to generate random numbers.

Comment: @Mdjon26 see my answer, you need to use std::fixed along with precision of 4 to get the desired result.

Comment: If you want to preserve the formatting codes, you might be interested in iof library at http://sf.net/projects/iof. It hasn't been updated in a while but it works great and nothing to build (it's all templates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use **std::fixed** and a setprecision of 4 to replicate printf's `%.4f`:

```
cout << ... << fixed << setprecision(4)  << number2  << ">\n";
```

Output:

```
Basic IO  ::
<383,  4.2088 >
<886,  9.7363 >
<777,  8.5385 >
<915,  10.0549>
```

See [here for more info](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) on std::setprecision and std::fixed.

Comment: That is not getting the correct output though. It's giving me <383,  4.20879>
 for the first line instead of <383, 4.2088> 
 which is the correct one. Although, it does get the last line correct.

Comment: Doh. Ok, should be fixed now. (No pun intended).